# d3 force layout: Does d3 require some order in the nodes to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a graph visualizer toy project. I want to be able to give it either an edge list or adjacency list as input (in a textarea) and show me the corresponding graph drawing in an svg element. Graph described as edge list works, but adjacency list gives all nodes the same index somehow.

I have been hitting my head over a problem for the last couple of days. I give the same graph, when described as edge list it worked okay...

[image: Imgur]

, when described as adjacency list it gives this:

[image: Imgur]

Here is the part that takes a text input and converts it into adjacency/edge list:

```
export const getAdjacencyListFromText = (text: string) => {
  const tokenizedLines = getLines(text)
    .map(line => getTokensFromLine(line).map(token => Number(token)))
    .filter(tokens => tokens.length >= 2)

  const adjacencyList = tokenizedLines.reduce<AdjacencyList>((acc: any, current: any) => {
    const source = current[0]
    const neighbors = current.slice(1)
    acc[source] = neighbors
    return acc
  }, [])

  return adjacencyList
}
export const getEdgeListFromText = (text: string) =>
  getLines(text)
    .map(line => getTokensFromLine(line).map(e => Number(e)))
    .filter(lineTokens => lineTokens.length >= 2)
    .map(tokens => {
      const source = tokens[0]
      const target = tokens[1]
      const weight = tokens[2]
      if (tokens.length === 2) return { source, target }
      else if (tokens.length === 3) return { source, target, weight }
    }) as EdgeList
```

The part that creates the graph object:

```
export const getGraphFromAdjacencyList = (adjacencyList: AdjacencyList) => {
  const nodes = adjacencyList.reduce<G.Node>((acc: G.Node[], current: AdjacencyListEntry, index: number) => {
    current.forEach(node => acc.push({ id: node }))
    if (!acc.some(el => el.id === index)) acc.push({ id: index })
    return acc
  }, []) as G.Node[]

  const links = nodes.reduce<G.Link>((acc: G.Link[], currentNode: G.Node) => {
    const neighbors = adjacencyList[currentNode.id]
    if (neighbors === undefined) return acc
    const newLinks = neighbors
      .map(neighborId => ({ source: currentNode.id, target: neighborId }))
      .filter(link => !acc.some(l => l.source === link.source && l.target === link.target))
    return acc = acc.concat(newLinks)
  }, [])

  return { nodes, links }
}

export const getGraphFromEdgeList = (edgeList: EdgeList) => {
  const nodes = edgeList.reduce<G.Node>((acc: G.Node[], currentEdge) => {
    const { source, target } = currentEdge
    if (!acc.some(n => n.id === source)) {
      acc.push({ id: source })
    }
    if (!acc.some(n => n.id === target)) {
      acc.push({ id: target })
    }
    return acc
  }, [])

  return {
    links: edgeList,
    nodes,
  }
}
```

And the part where I give that graph to d3:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { links: edgeData, nodes: nodeData } = this.props.graph

    // newNodes and newLinks is done so that old nodes and links keep their position
    // goal is better visuals
    const previousNodes = this.simulation.nodes()
    const newNodes = nodeData.map(node => {
      const existingNode = _(previousNodes).find((n: any) => n.id === node.id)
      if (existingNode !== undefined) {
        return existingNode
      } else {
        return node
      }
    })

    const previousLinks = this.simulation.force("link").links()
    const newLinks = edgeData.map(edge => {
      const existingLink = _(previousLinks).find((l: any) => l.source.id === edge.source && l.target.id === edge.target)
      if (existingLink !== undefined) {
        return existingLink
      } else {
        return edge
      }
    })

    const line = this.edgeLayer.selectAll("g").data(newLinks)
    const node = this.nodeLayer.selectAll("g").data(newNodes)

    node.exit().remove()
    line.exit().remove()

    this.node = this.createNode(node)
    this.edge = this.createEdge(line)

    this.simulation = this.simulation.nodes(newNodes)
    this.simulation.force("link").links(newLinks).id(d => d.id)
    this.simulation.on("tick", this.simulationTick)
    this.simulation.alphaTarget(1)
    this.simulation.restart()
  }
```

The graph object from the ***adjacency list*** is this:

```
{ 
     nodes: [ { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 3 } ],
     links: [ { source: 2, target: 3 }, { source: 1, target: 2 } ] }
}
```

The graph object from the ***edge list*** is this:

```
{     
     nodes: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ],
     links: [ { source: 1, target: 2 }, { source: 1, target: 3 } ]
}
```

The only difference was the *order of the nodes in the nodes array*.
So after one whole afternoon of writing test cases for my edge list and adjacency list utility function, I decide to sort my nodes before giving them to d3...and it works...

[image: Imgur]

Why would order matter?
I went to check in the documentation, and nowhere (that I saw so far) mentions any importance related to order of the nodes. I am puzzled.

Comment: I don't see it in your code blocks, but you need to [specify the id](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#link_id) property for the source/target nodes, the default is node index. If using the default id accessor - node order matters.

Comment: @AndrewReid you are right, right after writing the post I noticed the missing id specification. I added it like `links(newLinks).id(d => d.id)`, removed the sorting, but I get the same results.
Also I noticed that `1 2 3 4 5` works fine, but adding another `2 3 4 5` after it, the nodes index change in svg, then if I keep adding more nodes, I get out of memory and sometimes my ubuntu crashes.

Comment: I don't think it's so surprising right, depending on the order of the nodes the force ticks will do different things. What the tick does to a particular node is influenced by the position of other nodes, so if I do my tick on 1 and 1 moves, then I do a tick on 2 it might not be the same as 2 then 1 since 1 is in a different position in the two cases.

Comment: @Countingstuff The issue is not the shape. The indices are wrong. In the first screenshot, all the nodes have correct indices from 1 to 6, in the second one there is the correct *number* of nodes but the indices of each node are wrong, there are 5 `1`s and 1 `2`, even though the graph object given is the same, except for the *order* of the nodes in the node array, which I believe shouldn't make a difference. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so my graph was working in the EdgeList case out of coincidence I believe.

It seems that I was using `selectAll` for nodes and links inside my `tick` function when I should have been using `select` instead.
My `getAdjacencyListFromText` also used to give duplicate nodes/links sometimes, I removed that bug.

Result:

`simulationTick`

```
  simulationTick = () => {
    const { width, height } = this.props
    const keepBounded = (p: Point) => ({
      ...p,
      x: Math.max(0, Math.min(p.x, width)),
      y: Math.max(0, Math.min(p.y, height)),
    })

    const processPoint = (p: Point) => keepBounded(p)

    const setEdgeAttributes = edge =>
      edge
        .attr("x1", d => processPoint(d.source).x)
        .attr("y1", d => processPoint(d.source).y)
        .attr("x2", d => processPoint(d.target).x)
        .attr("y2", d => processPoint(d.target).y)

    const setNodeAttributes = node =>
      node.attr("transform", d => {
        const p = processPoint(d)
        return "translate(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")"
      })

    setEdgeAttributes(this.edge.select("line"))
    setNodeAttributes(this.node)
  }
```

inside `createNode` function, changed `selectAll` to `select`:

```
  createNode = node => {
    const nodeGroup = node

    const nodeGroupEnter = nodeGroup.enter().append("g")

    // here
    const nodeCircle = nodeGroup.select("circle")
    const nodeLabel = nodeGroup.select("text")
    // here

    const nodeCircleEnter = nodeGroupEnter.append("circle")
    nodeCircleEnter(...)

    const nodeLabelEnter = nodeGroupEnter.append("text")
    nodeLabelEnter(...)

    return nodeGroupEnter.merge(nodeGroup).attr("id", d => d.id)
  }
```

same for `createEdge`:

```
  createEdge = edge => {
    const edgeGroup = edge

    const edgeGroupEnter = edgeGroup.enter().append("g")

    // here
    const edgeLine = edgeGroup.select("line")
    const edgeLabel = edgeGroup.select("text")
    // here

    const edgeLineEnter = edgeGroupEnter.append("line")
    edgeLineEnter (...)

    const edgeLabelEnter = edgeGroupEnter.append("text")
    edgeLabelEnter (...)
    return edgeGroupEnter.merge(edgeGroup)
  }
```